# Apply Pixel Perfect by script in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity, gui, pixel

How can I apply Pixel Perfect by script in Unity? All I could find on the web is [this](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Canvas-pixelPerfect.html) which does help at all..

Comment: http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/06/19/pixel-perfect-2d/

Comment: Are you asking how to toggle the Pixel Perfect box on a given Canvas? Your link to the script reference seems to answer that... Maybe you can clarify why that doesn't help?

Comment: You need to set the orthographic camera's size so that each asset pixel renders ton an integer number of screen pixels. I have made a simple script that calculates that for you and adjusts the camera's size. You can get it for free from the asset store: https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/64563

Answer (score 1):

You need to override pixel perfect inheritance first if the GameObject's Canvas component is not considered the root canvas.

```
myNewUIGameObject.GetComponent <Canvas> ().overridePixelPerfect = true;
myNewUIGameObject.GetComponent <Canvas> ().pixelPerfect = true;
```

or

```
myCanvas.overridePixelPerfect = true;
myCanvas.pixelPerfect = true;
```